# get_author_posts_url() Not working

Tags: author, genesis-theme-framework

All in *single.php* file in *Genesis child theme*.

I have an `echo` of `divs` and in between I in one of the `anchors` I am trying to insert author's post url via a `variable`, like so:

```
function my_function() {
$author         = get_the_author_meta( $post->post_author );

$author_link    = get_author_posts_url($author);
$author_avatar  = get_avatar_url(get_the_author_meta( $post->post_author ));
$featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
          //..
      echo '<div>
                // ..
                    <div class="">
                        By <a href="'.$author_link.'">Author</a>
                    </div>'
            </div>
}

genesis();
```

I have tried: 
`the_author_posts_url();`, 
`get_the_author_meta('user_url');`, 
`get_author_posts_url();`, `get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );`
every time the link is either empty or it generates

```
http://localhost/author
```

without outputting the specific author.

full code of single.php is here:

function custom_entry_content() {
    $author         = get_the_author_meta( $post->post_author );

```
$author_link    = get_author_posts_url($author);
$author_avatar  = get_avatar_url(get_the_author_meta( $post->post_author ));
$featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

  echo '<div style="margin-bottom: 50px;position: relative; text-align:center; width:100%;background-image: url('.$featured_image[0].');
          height: 502px;    background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;">
          <div class="post-title-box">
            <h1 class="the-title">
                '. get_the_title(). '</h1>
                    </div>

            <div class="post-auth-info">
                <div class="vertical-middle" style="display:inline-block">

                        <div class="">
                            By <a href="'.$author_link.'">Author</a>
                        </div>

                        <time class="mk-publish-date" datetime="2017-11-01">
                            <a href="#">Published ' . time_elapsed_string(get_the_date()). '</a>
                        </time>
                </div>
                <div style="display:inline-block">
                    <a href="'.$author_link.'">
                <div>
                            <img alt="" src="'.$author_avatar.'" class="img-circle avatar avatar-55 " height="55" width="55" style="height:55px;width:55px">
                </div>
              </a>
                </div>
                    </div>

          </div>';
}

// Removes Published by and time data from before the post content area
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12);

add_filter( 'genesis_attr_site-inner', 'remove_top_padding');
function remove_top_padding( $attributes ) {
    $attributes['class'] = 'container box nopadding';
return $attributes;
}

// Adds left padding to content
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_content', 'padding_left');
function padding_left( $attributes ) {
    if ( 'full-width-content' === genesis_site_layout() )
    $attributes['class'] = '';
    else
    $attributes['class'] = 'col-md-8 single-post-entry';
return $attributes;
}

genesis();
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where you run this function `single_post_content`? and you didn't set the `$author` you can use the `get_the_author_meta('ID');` to get the current post author ID or the global `$post->post_author`

Comment: @Shibi this is single.php file on the root of the child theme

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't notice it's for genesis framework I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: where's `$author`  defined?

Comment: @inarilo I have updated the code with the definition, still the all the same it outputs http://localhost/author/     - without the actual author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone, who helped, it appears that the main problem was that I did not have `global $post` declared inside the function.

Also after tweaking the author_id declaration everything started working, here is the final code:

```
function single_post_entry() {
  global $post;
      $author_id      = $post->post_author;
      $author_link    = get_author_posts_url( $author_id );
      $author_avatar  = get_avatar_url( $author_id );
      $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

      // ..
 echo '<div>
             By <a href="' . esc_url( $author_link ) . '">Author</a>
       </div>';
}
```

Comment: you should accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

[get_the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/)

[get_author_posts_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/)

[get_avatar_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/)

You are using all three of these functions incorrectly. Please always check the documentation first. `get_the_author_meta()` does not require any arguments, but you can supply the field you wish to be returned. `get_author_posts_url()` requires the user_id. `get_author_posts_url()` and this one is a bit more flexible and will take a user_id or various Objects.

The code sample below should work...

```
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$author_link    = get_author_posts_url( $author_id );
$author_avatar  = get_avatar_url( $author_id );
$featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

echo '<div>
        <div class="">
            By <a href="' . esc_url( $author_link ) . '">Author</a>
        </div>
    </div>';
```